# Xcode 8 Constraints in TableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I have an issue with constraints in my TableViewController. I have put all necessary constraints (I think so), but when I run my app - it looks like a mess. It's really strange for me, because I have one ViewController where I put two table views in one time, used similar constraints and they work pretty fine on different devices. But here is a mess when I run it anywhere.

Here is screenshot of my constraints:

[image]
And here is how it looks like when app is running:[image: app is running]

What am I doing wrong? I've checked several questions on stackoverflow, but didn't get it.

Comment: try adding top constraints

Comment: Didn't help to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I have found solution, but not the root cause.
I have removed my TableViewController and created new one, put there labels, segues and so on. Then I have added constraints. And... it works! It looks like some XCode bug or something like that.

Previously I have an issue with Navigation Controller and Back button disappearance. And by re-adding Navigation Controller and some views and segues issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Add a distance constraint between the text and Name of the item. Then add a constraint from Name of item to the top of the cell.

**EDIT**
Try to put the text and Name of the item inside a vertically `UIStackView` and set the certain constraints for it. I think this will solve your problem

Comment: Hey. Tried, but no luck. It really does not make sense, I've tried a lot of things but labels are in the same position every time. http://imgur.com/a/hMsut  http://imgur.com/a/UNPnL

Comment: If it will be okay for you, I can share project for you. But need some time to translate some buttons from russian :-)

Comment: Hey, try what i edited in the answer. If that doesn't works let me know

Comment: Hi. Tried, but still the same. Nothing changed :( http://imgur.com/a/Lhsi7

Comment: Looks like I have found solution, but not the root cause.
I have removed my TableViewController and created new one, put there labels, segues and so on. Then I have added constraints. And... it works! It looks like some XCode bug or something like that.

Previously I have an issue with Navigation Controller and Back button disappearance. And by re-adding Navigation Controller and some views and segues issue was resolved.